# Extracting tree from multi graph with cheapest edge cost

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want this that I have 4 edges with each node and there is cost attached to it.Suppose I have a,b,c and d nodes.And I have cost attached to it in such a way that if I attached b nodes on top ,down,left or right of a node then they have different cost for each edge connected .Now I want to get a tree whicg give me minimum cost spanning tree ?If you want any further xplaination then I can provide you just message me.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 4 edges with each node and there is cost attached to it.

This is what we call a weighted graph.

> Now I want to get a tree which give me minimum cost spanning tree ?

There are several algorithms for this purpose, explaining them would go far beyond the purpose of SO. Generally these algorithms are discussed in a *"Algorithms & datastructures"-like* course.

Take a look at Prim's, Kruskal's, ... algorithms.
My personal favorite is Kruskal's algorithm, as it is really easy to implement and relatively performant (O(E log V) , E = # edges, V = # nodes).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Classic_algorithms) are some algorithms.

> If you want any further xplaination then I can provide you just message me.

We are not going to implement it for you. Have a look at the algorithms I pointed out, they should not be that hard to implement. If you take Kruskal's algorithm all you have to do is implement or search for an implementation of the `set` datastructure (which supports invocations of `union` and `find`). Once you'll have the set datastructure, implementing Kruskal will be straightforward.

Comment: Dear sir,
I don't want anyone to implement it.I know about krushkal,prims algorithm.But I think that you don't get my question correctly.i want to find minimum spanning tree from multigraph i.e to be more specific each node have 4 edges.I just want to know about the name of algorithm.

Comment: I don't see in what the solution would be different because each node has 4 edges. It still is a graph and that's what these algorithms work on (maybe you could use the information that each node has 4 edges to choose a more performant algorithm or to improve one, however Prim's, Kruskal's, ... algorithms are still usable.

Comment: Dear Sir,
Prim's and krushkal algorithms are greedy algorithms.They dont gurantee you success.But it give you greedy based result.I want to make sure that result is 100% sure.This is the reason that these two algorithms is not working for me.